# Targetting Id's & Classes in an iFrame

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

Basically, I'm using a plugin called Sentry Login. I'm currently hosting it on a site through an iframe. All works fine however, once a user clicks the sign up button, they're brought to the next page which says 'thanks for registering etc etc please verify your account using the link we emailed you' In the next paragraph, there is a link which returns the user to the login page but when they return to the login page using this link, it shows the home page inside the Iframe! To make matters worse, once they've clicked the link they can access any part of the site. I've contacted sentry who advise that the form is not built for iFrames, however, my question is this:

Would it be possible to target the elements within the iFrame from my end? If I could target the input button (which i've tried to do, to no avail) I could work it out from there but I've had no success. I've tried 101 things but I'm starting to think this is not possible. Can anyone make a suggestion on how to do this using jquery?

Thank you

Comment: Im sorry - just to clarify, my aim is that when the user clicks on that submit button and goes to the page with the login button, that the link on this page will bring them to the login page in the main window, rather than in the iframe

Comment: It sounds like your problem is that the iframe is being redirected and not the parent page.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: I have a suggestion, if the iframe and the parent page have the same domain, you can redirect the parent page like this with JavaScript; `window.parent.document.getElementById('iframe').src = 'URL here';`

Comment: The iframe needs to be on the same domain, otherwise you can't access anything inside it.

Comment: thanks for the quick responses and the welcome guys -im not quite sure what you mean by same domain, but if it helps the content thats in the iframe is served from the Sentry login site, I used an iFrame builder to house it, tried targetting every element to no avail. www139 thanks for that- i did already try that but no luck. I've even contacted the company to ask if they could help but they wont remove the link. Thanks again.

Comment: What @trug said. The browser won't let you control the contents of an iFrame to a different domain/website.

Comment: thanks Tokn, I had assumed that was the problem from the beginning, I was more hoping that there might be a workaround